# Finding likelihood function and maximum likelihood estimate

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference

Genetic theory shows that in a population in which the gene frequency for colour
blindness is $\theta$ then the probability that a male is colour blind is θ and the probability
that a female is colour blind is $\theta^2$
.
A random sample of 50 males is found to include 5 who are colour blind.Write down
the likelihood function and obtain the maximum likelihood estimate $\hat{\theta}_m$.
A second independent random sample of 100 females is found to include 4 who are
colour blind. Again write down the likelihood function and obtain the maximum
likelihood estimate $\hat{\theta}_f$ .
Now find the likelihood function for $\theta$ based on both samples and obtain the combined
maximum likelihood estimate $\hat{\theta}$. Comment on what you see.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Given that the probability of being a color blind man is $\theta$, the likelihood of a sample with $n_{m}$ men out of which $b_{m}$ are color blind is $\theta^{b_{m}}(1-\theta)^{n_{m}-b_{m}}$. By maximizing logarithm of this expression with respect to $\theta$, one gets $\hat{\theta}^{MLE}(n_{m},b_{m})=\frac{b_{m}}{n_{m}}$. Using similar approach for women and the two samples combined, you can get the other estimates. I believe the three estimates should be $\frac{1}{10}$, $\frac{1}{5}$ and $\frac{1}{100}(\sqrt{601}-9)$.

Comment: Would the second answer not be equal to 1/25? Because it'd be 4/100.. Never mind I realised that for women its θ^2

Comment: So would the likelihood for both functions combined then be (/theta^9)*(1-/theta)^141

Comment: No, since the probability that males are blind is $\theta$ and probability that females are blind is $\theta^{2}$.